# Usage of strtok()

Tags: c, strtok

I tried my `insertItem()` list api inserting all types of items, successfully, for example, strings(below),

```
static void copyData(List *records, char *delim, char *argv[]){

char *item = malloc(5);
    strcpy(item, "abcd");
    int count = 0;
    while(count++ < 10){

      insertItem(records, item);

      item = malloc(5);
      strcpy(item, "efgh");
    }
}
```

---

Output:

```
$ ./frequencyCounter.exe ARRAY
Key is:abcd
Key is:efgh
Key is:efgh
Key is:efgh
Key is:efgh
Key is:efgh
Key is:efgh
Key is:efgh
Key is:efgh
Key is:efgh
Size of list: 10
Before freeList()After freeList()
```

---

But `strtok()` tokens shows problem code, as shown below, `buf[]` parameter not required above,

```
static void copyData(List *records, char buf[], char *delim, char *argv[]){

  char *token =  strtok(buf, delim);

  void *item = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
  item = memcpy(item, token, strlen(token)+1);
    printf("token-%s\n", token);        
  while(token != NULL){

    insertItem(records, item);
    token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    if(token != NULL){
      printf("token-%s\n", token);        
      item = malloc(strlen(token) + 1); //every item has its own heap memory
      memcpy(item, token, strlen(token)+1);
    }
  }

}
```

---

Output is,

```
$ ./frequencyCounter.exe ARRAY
token-it
token-was
token-the
token-best
token-of
token-times
Key is:it
Key is:it
Key is:it
Key is:it
Key is:it
Key is:it
Size of list: 6
Aborted (core dumped)
```

---

In the problem code(above), Can we re-use the result of `strtok()`?

Comment: Just worthwhile noting, `strtok` might not be the function you want to use. `strsep` or `strtok_r` are likely better functions for whatever you are doing, even according to `strtok`'s man page.

Comment: You probably want `malloc(5)`.

Comment: `strtok` doesn't allocate memory, it just modifies the contents of `buf[]` and returns a pointer to some location in `buf[]`. So you still need to `malloc` and `strcpy`.

Comment: @user3386109 After allocating memory and strcpy, it doesnot work. I did not paste that code, but let me do that now

Comment: When copying strings, reserve one byte for the terminating zero: `malloc(strlen(token));` -> `malloc(strlen(token)+1);`. You did this right on the `memcpy`. (If your compiler supports `strdup`: that would take care of this.)

Comment: @RadLexus See the updated code.

Comment: Most of these functions return `NULL` on failure, `malloc()`, `strtok()`. You have to check for that, specially `strtok()`.

Comment: Um, but you have another `malloc` ...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am `malloc`ing using `strlen()` in second case

Comment: Please post the actual code, which one is the `insertItem()` function? Also, format it so it's easily readable but any one that is not you or the compiler.

Comment: `item = malloc(strlen(token)); memcpy(item, token, strlen(token)+1);`. That's a buffer overflow. Trying to copy 1 more byte than was allocated space for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it's quite hard to understand or read your code, the following looks bad

```
item = malloc(strlen(token));
```

you then `memcpy()` `strlen(token) + 1` bytes.

This will cause undefined behavior and thus your program will behave erratically.

Also, don't overuse `strlen()` it iterates through all the characters of the input string every time you call it, instead just store the result somewhere if you will need to use it more than once.

This is an improved version of your function

```
static void 
copyData(List *records, char buf[], char *delim, char *argv[])
{
    char *token;
    size_t length;
    void *item;

    token = strtok(buf, delim);
    if (token == NULL)
        return;
    length = strlen(token);
    item = malloc(length + 1);
    if (item == NULL)
        return;
    memcpy(item, token, length + 1);

    printf("token-%s\n", token);        
    while (token != NULL) {
        insertItem(records, item);

        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        if (token != NULL) {
            length = strlen(token);

            item = malloc(length + 1); // every item has its own heap memory
            if (item != NULL) {
                memcpy(item, token, length + 1);
            }
            printf("token-%s\n", token);
        }
    }
    // Some day, you will have to free these pointers
}
```

But I hope it's not just like this, because every `item` you `malloc()` will never be `free`d and also, because it violates the DRY principle somewhat. And one more thing, you can use `strdup()` too.